# Where does a HttpContext value get stored

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know, if I store a value using  HttpContext.Current.Items.Add, where does it get stored? Is it on the Server, or client side like ViewState?

Will storing values in HttpContext.Current.Items.Add give problems in a Web farm situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It is stored in the **thread storage** area.

I am not going into much detail for asynchronous processing when thread changes but in a context switch, context gets copied - *I believe*.

Answer (score 3):

It is stored in the memory of the server and the value is available for the entire lifetime of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the HTTPContext is stored on the server it comes from the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.Items is basically an IDictionary object (hashtable) whose scope is the life of the request.

See https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx